# Am I violating the Single Responsibility Principle with this AST Node of mine?

Tags: design

We are building an interpreter for a language as part of the requirements in one of our undergraduate course. Part of the project involves writing a lexer and a parser. The parser generates an AST. Obviously, the AST would have nodes.

One of the nodes of that AST is the `ArithmeticOperationNode`. This node will be a node containing any operations involving arithmentic. The code below is a minimized version of the node.

```
package ds.ast;

import exceptions.CompilerException;
import exceptions.RuntimeException;

public class ArithmeticOperationNode extends OperationNode
{
    public ArithmeticOperationNode(String operation, Computable operator1, Computable operator2, int startingLine, int startingColumn)
    {
        super(operation, operator1, operator2, startingLine, startingColumn);
    }

    public Value compute() throws RuntimeException, CompilerException
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: `OperationNode` implements an interface called `Computable`.

`compute()` will be responsible for performing the arithmetic operation between `operator1` and `operator2`. `operator1` and `operator2` may be another arithmetic expression. The function will be called when we traverse the AST during execution. There are a lot of nodes that follow the same design, i.e. having a `compute()` function.

**Am I violating the Single Responsibility Principle with this?** I have a feeling that I am doing so.

Comment: I don't really see why...the primary purpose of AST nodes in an interpreter is to be interpreted, which for expressions would be to compute a value. This seems like a single responsibility. What do you see as conflicting responsibilities?

Comment: @JacquesB, do correct me on this. The way I see it is that, an "evaluator" would be the one that will execute the whole AST tree. The parser would just generate the AST. And lastly, the nodes will just hold data, and be, well, nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There do seem to be some conflation of responsibilites in that you have syntax level information (operation indicated as a string, line nr etc.) together with the semantic operation. I suspect `compute()` will end up having code similar to this (pseudocode):

```
if operation=="+":
  return a + b
if operation=="-":
  return a - b
...
```

Here the interpretation of the syntax is conflated with the semantics of the evaluation. The AST shouldn't really depend on the concrete syntax, which is why it is called an *Abstract* Syntax Tree. Instead the parser could generate AST classes like `AddExpression`, `SubstractionExpression` etc. which would only contain the semantic operation in `compute()` but not have any knowledge of the underlying syntax.

Comment: Your suspicion is correct. It also has some type checking which I believe, should also be delegated somewhere else. So, I should just move the responsibility of `compute()` somewhere else, like what Martin Maat suggested?

Comment: Essentially, making the node only contain data? Also, can you explain what "semantics of the evaluation" is?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais: No I would actually suggest the opposite, that `compute()` do belong in the AST class in an interpreter, but the concerns related to the syntax does not. By the semantics I mean the actual effect of the operation as opposed to the syntax.

Comment: After much thinking, I think I'll be placing the responsibilities of `compute()` into the class that will execute the whole AST. If I don't, I'd be creating unused "variables" but that's already outside the scope of this question and you might get confused. On the other hand, I will decompose my `ArithmeticOperationNode` into `AddExpression` and the like, just like you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais: If you move the compute() out of the AST nodes, then you lose the benefit of having distinct classes for the AST nodes. Unless you add some kind of visitor pattern, in which case you get a lot of overhead for no significant benefit.

Comment: I don't see how moving `compute()` out would make me lose the benefit of distinct classes. Please enlighten me. My concern is that, having `compute()` inside the nodes means that the parser would have to "create" the "variables" beforehand along with an AST. I was thinking that any variable object (not sure with proper term) should be created during execution, and not during the generation of the AST.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais: What do you mean "variables"? Do you mean the variable declarations and references in the language? They would also need to be part of the AST. But the runtime values would be in a seperate "environment" which would be passed to "compute()".

Comment: By variables, I meant the variables that are created when the AST tree is executed. Like, if the evaluator (the thing that will traverse the tree), hits a variable declaration, a variable will be created in memory. In my case, it'll supposedly be a new object created. But if `compute()` is in the nodes, I'm thinking that I these variables will be pre-created so that I could pass them to the nodes that have `compute()`.

Comment: Yes you will have to create an object representing the active bindings and pass it to the evaluation function...but you have to do that in any case, even if you place compute() somewhere else than in the AST. And if you place compute() somewhere else than in the AST you will end up with code like in the example.

Comment: Wouldn't I also be creating active binding objects even though they are unused? Wouldn't that be a waste of memory especially in large programs?

Comment: I agree with everything Jacques said. Having a `compute()` methods in the AST is absolutely fine, especially if this is just a simple calculator language. But in my experience, using a separate Visitor that interprets the AST is preferable for more complicated languages, and makes it easier to manage bindings or complex control flow. Without a visitor, all the state that a visitor could hold would have to be passed as explicit params (`compute(variableBindings, functions)`) which doesn't waste anything, but gets increasingly inconvenient. Bindings/environments can simply be a HashMap.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais: You lost me there - are you performing some optimization where you remove unused variables in the interpreted language? I doubt that would be worthwhile, but in any case I don't see how that should make a difference. Maybe I would need to see a code example to understand what the issue is exactly.

Comment: Thinking about it, indeed, I guess I don't need to remove unused variables. Probably just set a warning in say, a log. My other concern is when the user creates a variable in a branch that is relatively unreachable. Even though the variable will be unused, I still would have to create binding references for those statements in the unreachable branch. I create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/seanballais/631502c10f8ceebfb9c0a24d1cdcffc9) to make things clearer.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais: But why are you even concerned about the cost of unreachable code? Is this a significant issue in the codebase?

Comment: For now, not really an issue. I was just thinking of possible worst cases that I could address as early as now. Or is this just a result of overthinking (which prolly includes worrying about the SRP)?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais: I definitely think you are overthinking it - this is an interpreted language after all. It is going to be relatively inefficient anyway. Optimizations like dead-code elimination is not a trivial task in an interpreted language.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the guidance, @JacquesB. I'll be keeping `compute()` as is, setting bindings even though there is not assurance that they will be used, and decompose `ArithmeticOperationNode` a bit further.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are. It may be because of your naming. You call your object ArithmeticOperation, already suggesting it does something. While at parse time it is still just an expression. Later in your question you do use that word (expression) which is really the better word in an AST context. You would not feel the need to add a Compute() method if the thing were called ArithmeticExpression.

I think the better route would be to recognize expressions rather than operations. You have two kinds: Unary and binary. As goes for operators: unary operators (like not) and binary operators (and, plus).

Comment: Basing from your answer, I believe I should rename my `ArithmeticOperation` object to `ArithmeticExpression`, and delegate the task of computing for the expression to the module that will traverse through AST during execution. Correct?

Comment: @Sean I think that would be better. The AST should just be a dissection of your code, it is not a processor.

Comment: In other words, just let the *damn* tree be a tree? Haha.